# OpenMP For Inside a For Loop Without Terminating the Parallel Region

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm working with OpenMP in C to parallelize my program. I have a code like this:

```c
for (num = 0; num < NUM_DATA; num++) {
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_AB; i++) {
        A[i] = some_calc(data[num], B[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_AB; i++) {
        B[i] = other_calc(A[i]);
    }
}
```

I parallelize my code into something like this:

```c
for (num = 0; num < NUM_DATA; num++) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_AB; i++) {
            A[i] = some_calc(data[num], B[i]);
        }

        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_AB; i++) {
            B[i] = other_calc(A[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the parallelized code, I got a much worse running time than the serial version. From what I've learned, this happened because, at the end of each `num` iteration, the created parallel region is terminated by the `#pragma omp parallel`'s closing bracket, but the parallel region must be created again at the next `num` iteration. The parallel scheme will be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uunqE.png).

Because of this, parallel overhead (for creating a parallel region) hits the program each `num` loop, instead of just once. Is there any way to make the program to not terminate created parallel region for the next `num` iteration? Or any other workarounds in mind?

I can't parallelize this code into something like this:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for
for (num = 0; num < NUM_DATA; num++) {
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_AB; i++) {
            A[i] = some_calc(data[num], B[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < NUM_AB; i++) {
            B[i] = other_calc(A[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

because of the `B` used in `some_calc()` for any `num` iteration depends on the `other_calc()` from previous `num-1` iteration.

Comment: In your outer for loop you are incrementing `i` not `num`. Have you profiled the code execution or are you guessing at what the problem is?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mistyped that. What do you mean by "profiled the code?"

Comment: Have you actually measured the time spent in each of the loops for both the single and multi-threaded versions? Do you actually know precisely where the difference in run-time comes from or, are you guessing?

Comment: What are the values for `NUM_DATA` and `NUM_AB`? What kind of data is stored in the A and B arrays? I grant that OMP overheads can be high in certain places, but they may actually be small compared to other effects.

Comment: I doubt using parallel on the inner region is causing the performance to be worse than the serial code.  You need to provide more information. How are you timing your code (I hope you're not using `clock()`)?  What compiler and OS? What compiler options are you using? What optimization level are you using (e.g. are you using `-O3` with GCC?).

Comment: Keep in mind that OpenMP implementations create a thread pool on the first iteration of the parallel region. Further iterations normally don't need to delete or create threads as the treads are already in the pool. This reduces the overhead significantly.

Comment: You can trivially transform the code by moving `#pragma omp parallel` outside of the parallel region and making sure `num` is declared locally or private. However, as Zboson mentioned, this may not be the issue.

Comment: I already measure the time spent in each `num` loops, and its way worse than the serial version.

Comment: `NUM_DATA` is around 1500 and `NUM_AB` is around 100 (defined using `#define` statement). The `A` and `B` arrays store some `double` data.

Comment: I'm using `clock()` for time measure because the program is too fast for `omp_get_wtime()`. Any other options for measuring the time? I'm using GCC-64 on Windows. I just use `-fopenmp` option.

Comment: So, the parallel region will not be terminated even if the program already passes the `#pragma omp parallel` curly braces?

Comment: Your have at least three major problems: you use `clock()`, you donæt use optimization, the time of your test is too small for benchmarking.  The 64-bit version of GCC on Windows uses the *nix C runtime libraries which calculate the cumulative time for each cpu. The 32-bit version of GCC on Windows uses the MSVC C runtime which does not do this.  Use `omp_get_wtime()`. Use `-O3` and increase the size of your test so that it runs for at least 1 second.

Comment: *I'm using clock() for time measure because the program is too fast for omp_get_wtime()* If that's true don't waste your time trying to make it go faster.